# Python property descriptor design: why copy rather than mutate?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties, mutators

I was looking at how Python implements the [property descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties) internally. According to the docs `property()` is implemented in terms of the descriptor protocol, reproducing it here for convenience:

```
class Property(object):
    "Emulate PyProperty_Type() in Objects/descrobject.c"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj)

    def getter(self, fget):
        return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def setter(self, fset):
        return type(self)(self.fget, fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        return type(self)(self.fget, self.fset, fdel, self.__doc__)
```

My question is: why aren't the last three methods implemented as follows:

```
    def getter(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget
        return self

    def setter(self, fset):
        self.fset = fset
        return self

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        self.fdel= fdel
        return self
```

Is there a reason for returing new instances of property, internally pointing to basically the same get and set functions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's start with a bit of history, because the original implementation had been equivalent to your alternative (equivalent because `property` is implemented in C in CPython so the `getter`, etc. are written in C not "plain Python").

However it was reported as [issue (1620) on the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue1620) back in 2007:

> As reported by Duncan Booth at
>   http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.general/551183 the new
>   @spam.getter syntax modifies the property in place but it should create
>   a new one.
>
> The patch is the first draft of a fix. I've to write unit tests to
>   verify the patch. It copies the property and as a bonus grabs the
>   `__doc__` string from the getter if the doc string initially came from the
>   getter as well.

Unfortunately the link doesn't go anywhere (I really don't know why it's called a "permalink" ...). It was classified as bug and changed to the current form (see [this patch](https://bugs.python.org/file8947/py3k_copy_property.patch) or the corresponding [Github commit (but it's a combination of several patches)](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0449f63f53fa0c2fcf779703d2db77d8a658cf7d#diff-a34ae826f869897e56e081e212b3d75a)). In case you don't want to follow the link the change was:

```
 PyObject *
 property_getter(PyObject *self, PyObject *getter)
 {
-   Py_XDECREF(((propertyobject *)self)->prop_get);
-   if (getter == Py_None)
-       getter = NULL;
-   Py_XINCREF(getter);
-   ((propertyobject *)self)->prop_get = getter;
-   Py_INCREF(self);
-   return self;
+   return property_copy(self, getter, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 }
```

And similar for `setter` and `deleter`. If you don't know C the important lines are:

```
((propertyobject *)self)->prop_get = getter;
```

and

```
return self;
```

the rest is mostly "Python C API boilerplate". However these two lines are equivalent to your:

```
self.fget = fget
return self
```

And it was changed to:

```
return property_copy(self, getter, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

which essentially does:

```
return type(self)(fget, self.fset, self.fdel, self.__doc__)
```

### Why was it changed?

Since the link is down I don't know the exact reason, however I can speculate based on the added [test-cases in that commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0449f63f53fa0c2fcf779703d2db77d8a658cf7d#diff-ea5875d237692b8c64af41a0dea6f3a9):

```
import unittest

class PropertyBase(Exception):
    pass

class PropertyGet(PropertyBase):
    pass

class PropertySet(PropertyBase):
    pass

class PropertyDel(PropertyBase):
    pass

class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._spam = 5

    @property
    def spam(self):
        """BaseClass.getter"""
        return self._spam

    @spam.setter
    def spam(self, value):
        self._spam = value

    @spam.deleter
    def spam(self):
        del self._spam

class SubClass(BaseClass):

    @BaseClass.spam.getter
    def spam(self):
        """SubClass.getter"""
        raise PropertyGet(self._spam)

    @spam.setter
    def spam(self, value):
        raise PropertySet(self._spam)

    @spam.deleter
    def spam(self):
        raise PropertyDel(self._spam)

class PropertyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_property_decorator_baseclass(self):
        # see #1620
        base = BaseClass()
        self.assertEqual(base.spam, 5)
        self.assertEqual(base._spam, 5)
        base.spam = 10
        self.assertEqual(base.spam, 10)
        self.assertEqual(base._spam, 10)
        delattr(base, "spam")
        self.assert_(not hasattr(base, "spam"))
        self.assert_(not hasattr(base, "_spam"))
        base.spam = 20
        self.assertEqual(base.spam, 20)
        self.assertEqual(base._spam, 20)
        self.assertEqual(base.__class__.spam.__doc__, "BaseClass.getter")

    def test_property_decorator_subclass(self):
        # see #1620
        sub = SubClass()
        self.assertRaises(PropertyGet, getattr, sub, "spam")
        self.assertRaises(PropertySet, setattr, sub, "spam", None)
        self.assertRaises(PropertyDel, delattr, sub, "spam")
        self.assertEqual(sub.__class__.spam.__doc__, "SubClass.getter")
```

That's similar to the examples the other answers already provided. The problem is that you want to be able to change the behavior in a subclass without affecting the parent class:

```
>>> b = BaseClass()
>>> b.spam
5
```

However with your property it would result in this:

```
>>> b = BaseClass()
>>> b.spam
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PropertyGet                               Traceback (most recent call last)
PropertyGet: 5
```

That happens because `BaseClass.spam.getter` (which is used in `SubClass`) actually modifies and returns the `BaseClass.spam` property!

So yes, it had been changed (very likely) because it allows to modify the behavior of a property in a subclass without changing the behavior on the parent class.

### Another reason (?)

Note that there is an additional reason, which is a bit silly but actually worth mentioning (in my opinion):

Let's recap shortly: A decorator is just syntactic sugar for an assignment, so:

```
@decorator
def decoratee():
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def func():
    pass

decoratee = decorator(func)
del func
```

The important point here is that the **result of the decorator** is assigned to the **name of the decorated function**. So while you generally use the same "function name" for the getter/setter/deleter - you don't have to!

For example:

```
class Fun(object):
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._a = value

>>> o = Fun()
>>> o.b = 100
>>> o.a
100
>>> o.b
100
>>> o.a = 100
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

In this example you use the descriptor for `a` to create another descriptor for `b` that behaves like `a` except that it got a `setter`.

It's a rather weird example and probably not used very often (or at all). But even if it's rather odd and (to me) not very good style - it should illustrate that just because you use `property_name.setter` (or `getter`/`deleter`) that it has to be bound to `property_name`. It could be bound to any name! And I wouldn't expect it to propagate back to the original property (although I'm not really sure what I would expect here).

### Summary

- CPython actually used the "modify and return `self`" approach in the `getter`, `setter` and `deleter` once.
- It had been changed because of a bug report.
- It behaved "buggy" when used with a subclass that overwrote a property of the parent class.
- More generally: Decorators cannot influence to what name they will be bound so the assumption that it's always valid to `return self` in a decorator might be questionable (for a general-purpose decorator).

Comment: +460 for digging up the history and those test-cases.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR - `return self` permits child classes to change the behaviour of their parents.  See MCVE of the failure below.

When you create property `x` in a parent class, that class has an attribute `x` with a particular setter, getter, and deleter.  The first time you say `@Parent.x.getter` or the like in a child class, you are invoking a method on the *parent's* `x` member.  If `x.getter` did not copy the `property` instance, calling it from the *child* class would change the *parent's* getter.  That would prevent the parent class from operating the way it was designed to.  (Thanks to Martijn Pieters (no surprise) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work#comment49685936_17330273).)

And besides, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) require it:

> A property object has getter, setter, and deleter methods usable as decorators that create a copy of the property ...

**An example, showing the internals:**

```
class P:
    ## @property  --- inner workings shown below, marked "##"
    def x(self):
        return self.__x
    x = property(x)                             ## what @property does

    ## @x.setter
    def some_internal_name(self, x):
        self.__x = x
    x = x.setter(some_internal_name)            ## what @x.setter does

class C(P):
    ## @P.x.getter   # x is defined in parent P, so you have to specify P.x
    def another_internal_name(self):
        return 42

    # Remember, P.x is defined in the parent.  
    # If P.x.getter changes self, the parent's P.x changes.
    x = P.x.getter(another_internal_name)         ## what @P.x.getter does
    # Now an x exists in the child as well as in the parent.
```

If `getter` mutated and returned `self` as you suggested, the child's `x` would be exactly the parent's `x`, and both would have been modified.

However, because the spec requires `getter` to return a copy, the child's `x` is a new copy with `another_internal_name` as `fget`, and the parent's `x` is untouched.

#### MCVE

It's a bit long, but shows the behaviour on Py 2.7.14.

```
class OopsProperty(object):
    "Shows what happens if getter()/setter()/deleter() don't copy"

    def __init__(self, fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.fdel = fdel
        if doc is None and fget is not None:
            doc = fget.__doc__
        self.__doc__ = doc

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.fset is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        self.fset(obj, value)

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        if self.fdel is None:
            raise AttributeError("can't delete attribute")
        self.fdel(obj)

    ########## getter/setter/deleter modified as the OP suggested
    def getter(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget
        return self

    def setter(self, fset):
        self.fset = fset
        return self

    def deleter(self, fdel):
        self.fdel = fdel
        return self

class OopsParent(object):   # Uses OopsProperty() instead of property()
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 0

    @OopsProperty
    def x(self):
        print("OopsParent.x getter")
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print("OopsParent.x setter")
        self.__x = x

class OopsChild(OopsParent):
    @OopsParent.x.getter                 # changes OopsParent.x!
    def x(self):
        print("OopsChild.x getter")
        return 42;

parent = OopsParent()
print("OopsParent x is",parent.x);

child = OopsChild()
print("OopsChild x is",child.x);

class Parent(object):   # Same thing, but using property()
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        print("Parent.x getter")
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        print("Parent.x setter")
        self.__x = x

class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.x.getter
    def x(self):
        print("Child.x getter")
        return 42;

parent = Parent()
print("Parent x is",parent.x);

child = Child()
print("Child x is",child.x);
```

And the run:

```
$ python foo.py
OopsChild.x getter              <-- Oops!  parent.x called the child's getter
('OopsParent x is', 42)         <-- Oops!
OopsChild.x getter
('OopsChild x is', 42)
Parent.x getter                 <-- Using property(), it's OK
('Parent x is', 0)              <-- What we expected from the parent class
Child.x getter
('Child x is', 42)
```

Answer (score 7):

So you can use properties with inheritance?

Just an attempt at answering by giving an example:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        self._value = val


class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._double = 0

    @Base.value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        Base.value.fset(self, val)
        self._double = val * 2
```

If it was implemented the way you write it, then the `Base.value.setter` would also set the double, which is not wanted. We want a brand new setter, not to modify the base one.

EDIT: as pointed out by @wim, in this particular case, not only it would modify the base setter, but we would also end up with a recursion error. Indeed the child setter would call the base one, which would be modified to call itself with `Base.value.fset` in an endless recursion.

Comment: Close.  The child setter would blow the recursion stack, I think.